# problem in understanding The Z channel

Tags: information-theory

My question is about the Z channel. The Z-channel  has binary input and output alphabet and transitions probabilities $p(y|x)$ givin by the following matrix:

$$    Q =\pmatrix{ 
    1 &0\\
    1/2 &1/2}$$
we want to find the capacity of Z-channel.

Here is the solution:

[image]

I have problem in realizing the solution. For example, I'm confused about the method that $H(Y|X)$ and $H(Y)$ is computed. Why we have considered only $Pr(Y=1)$ in computing $H(Y)$? Isn't it computed using this formula:

$p(y)=\Sigma p(y|x)p(x)$ and $H(y)= p(y) \log 1/p(y) $ ?

Comment: I've always disliked that notation (from Cover & Thomas) that uses $H(x)$ both for the entropy of the variable $x$ and for the binary entropy function (where the argument is a mathematical variable). Better call the latter $h()$ or $h_b()$ or something different to avoid confusions.

Comment: @leonbloy - well, $h$ is used by them for differential entropy. in any case, i think it rarely / never leads to confusion.

Comment: @Batman  "it rarely / never leads to confusion " Well, we have one example here. I've seen more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the equation for $H(Y)$, you mixed the standard entropy function $H$ and the highlighted binary entropy function $\textbf H$, which stands for the binary entropy function:$$\textbf H(p) = -p\log p-(1-p)\log(1-p)$$
On the other hand, the equation for $H(Y|X)$ follows directly from $$H(Y|X) = p(X=0)H(Y|X=0)+p(X=1)H(Y|X=1)$$
and noticing that $H(Y|X=0)=0$ and $H(Y|X=1)=1$.